# Heroku not deploying build due to dependency issue

Tags: heroku, shopify

while deploying build in heroku ,its causing an dependency error ,does anyone have faced the same ? What would be the root cause ? Any idea to resolve this ?
The heroku build used to work before but now this error happens and its confusing really

```
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
    remote:        Installing node modules
    remote:        npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    remote:        npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
    remote:        npm ERR! 
    remote:        npm ERR! While resolving: next@12.1.6
    remote:        npm ERR! Found: react@16.14.0
    remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react
    remote:        npm ERR!   react@"^16.10.1" from the root project
    remote:        npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0" from @apollo/react-common@3.1.4
    remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/@apollo/react-common
    remote:        npm ERR!     @apollo/react-common@"^3.1.4" from @apollo/react-components@3.1.5
    remote:        npm ERR!     node_modules/@apollo/react-components
    remote:        npm ERR!       @apollo/react-components@"^3.1.5" from @apollo/react-hoc@3.1.5
    remote:        npm ERR!       node_modules/@apollo/react-hoc
    remote:        npm ERR!         @apollo/react-hoc@"^3.1.5" from react-apollo@3.1.5
    remote:        npm ERR!         node_modules/react-apollo
    remote:        npm ERR!       1 more (react-apollo)
    remote:        npm ERR!     @apollo/react-common@"^3.1.4" from @apollo/react-hoc@3.1.5
    remote:        npm ERR!     node_modules/@apollo/react-hoc
    remote:        npm ERR!       @apollo/react-hoc@"^3.1.5" from react-apollo@3.1.5
    remote:        npm ERR!       node_modules/react-apollo
    remote:        npm ERR!         react-apollo@"^3.1.3" from the root project
    remote:        npm ERR!     3 more (@apollo/react-hooks, @apollo/react-ssr, react-apollo)
    remote:        npm ERR!   14 more (@apollo/react-components, @apollo/react-hoc, ...)
    remote:        npm ERR! 
    remote:        npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    remote:        npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0-0" from next@12.1.6
    remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/next
    remote:        npm ERR!   next@"^12.1.6" from the root project
    remote:        npm ERR!   peer next@">= 5.1.0" from next-env@1.1.1
    remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/next-env
    remote:        npm ERR!     next-env@"^1.1.0" from the root project
    remote:        npm ERR! 
    remote:        npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.1.0
    remote:        npm ERR! node_modules/react
    remote:        npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0-0" from next@12.1.6
    remote:        npm ERR!   node_modules/next
    remote:        npm ERR!     next@"^12.1.6" from the root project
    remote:        npm ERR!     peer next@">= 5.1.0" from next-env@1.1.1
    remote:        npm ERR!     node_modules/next-env
    remote:        npm ERR!       next-env@"^1.1.0" from the root project
    remote:        npm ERR! 
    remote:        npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    remote:        npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    remote:        npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    remote:        npm ERR! 
    remote:        npm ERR! See /tmp/npmcache.KnKS4/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
    remote:        
    remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.KnKS4/_logs/2022-06-03T12_47_36_545Z-debug-0.log
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Build failed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue a few days ago (early June) while deploying my React app on Heroku as well. It seems the problem was caused by the npm version update. By default, Heroku uses the latest stable version of node and npm as the building engines, but it might lead to conflicting dependencies if you use a previous version of them.

So, **if it works completely fine locally but this issue happens while deploying it on Heroku**, here is the solution:

Use `node --version` and `npm --version` to check out the versions on your local instance, and then add them under engines section in your package.json file, like this (replace 16.0.0 and 7.10.0 with the versions you have):

```
"engines": {
    "node": "16.0.0",
    "npm": "7.10.0"
},
```

then redeploy the app on Heroku. Problem should be fixed.

Comment: yes it worked when i specified versions in engines @ethan

Comment: Nope, didn't work for me.

Answer (score 8):

add `NPM_CONFIG_LEGACY_PEER_DEPS` environmental variable to your Heroku app and set its value to `true`.
[image]